# How to visualize nodes(agents) of Neural Network algorithms in a form in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, neural-network

These days I am trying to develop two algorithms in c#. Self Organizing Map, Particle Swarm Optimization and Glowworm Swarm optimization. I know how the algorithms work but there is an issue which I am not sure where to start from.

Agents in the search space which try to find the best solution have some coordinates(x and y). I don't know how am I should represent the position of agents visually in a form in each iteration. One option may be using charts in c# and represent point so that in each iteration I am going to change the position of the agent(point) in the chart. Another way may be using drawing classes in c# and drawing circles or points in a panel based on the x and y coordinates. Which classes of .net should I use to represents points in a search space visually(in a 2D space).

I hope you understood me and thank you for reading this post.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand. Where is the "code" question? If you want to represent a series of 3D connected dots, you should probably render them in a 3D space.

Comment: I'm not sure why would you want to draw it. It's not really a programming question, it is about representing multidimentional data. I don't think it is feasible in your case (and honestly you'll just see quite a mess of points, nothing interesting).

Comment: anyway you are right. Forget the multidimensional points. What do you suggest me for 2D. Should I use charts or should I just drive circles or points in a panel according to the agent`s current position (x,y)? Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your design variables are N-dimensional, N>3, it is not an easy job to visualize the entire domain of interest. You can either project the N-Dim to 2D or 3D to get a "section" of the fields.

Comment: anyway you are right. Forget the multidimensional points. What do you suggest me for 2D. Should I use charts or should I just drive circles or points in a panel according to the agent`s current position (x,y)? Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: It depends on your UI framework, if you can use WPF, this is trivial, and you can use, for instance, border + rectangle + TextBlock etc in XAML, it is very straightforward. If you use Winform, try use ZedGraph controls, see here http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/

Comment: Yes I am using Windows Forms but you made me curious for WPF. I know from java that I used to draw balls (namely points) in some games but I dont know the equivalent classes in c# for representing agents visually. Graphics maybe? Anyway I will check your suggestion.

Comment: I just want to remind you that redrawing will occur in every iteration so it should be something that works fast enough. I have a feeling that charts will be slower in such a case

Comment: redrawing is at your absolute control, and you can manually or periodically update your canvas, this is not a problem to a developer at all.

Comment: yes I will update it in each iteration but I dont know which will be faster. The Drawing and Graphing classes of .net or the Charts. Anyway I will try and see which will work better

Comment: @David.Thnx a lot. It seems quite good tool. I am going to use it. It has everything I need.